# Modeling a Cup cake wrapper when I apply the solidify modifer the normals get messed up and when I make transmission shader I get weird lighting efect

Tags: modeling, normals, solidify-modifier

I am modeling a cup cake. to create the wrapper I duplicated the bottom part of the cup cake and kept that as the wrapper.[image: cupcake model] [image: Cupcake wrapper with modifers]the model seems fine but when I apply the solidify modifer the model gets messed up since the thickness of the wrapper is only 0.03 mm the shape does not get messed up but when I increase the thickness or when I apply a make transmission 1 on the shader I noticed some weird effects.[image: rendered image with modifers] [image: without solidify modifer]

I checked the face orientation and I saw without the solidify modifer the orientation is fine but once the modifer comes into effect the orientation gets wrecked which I believe is the cause of the issue.[image: face orientation with solidify modifer] [image: without solidify modifer]

How do I fix this so I get a clean mesh/ model?

Comment: Hmm I think this actually happens because you are using subdivision after that solidify, try to swap it, pull subdivision above solidify, still same? Also try to check "Even Thickness" in the solidify

Comment: It seems like your inside and outside faces are practically overlapping because the thickness is so low. Have you tried increasing the thickness? You may need to check the scale of the objects in your scene or apply the scale on the wrapper to get the actual 0.03mm thickness you want. Also, it looks like the transmission shader is struggling because the wrapper intersects with the cupcake itself. Try scaling it up slightly. You may need to increase transmission bounces or tweak the shader using a Light Path node as well.

Comment: Yes it worked the order of modifers was wrong Subdivide and then solidify. thank you I cant believe I missed that out. :-)